# Generate rounded timestamps with remote server allowing for latency

Tags: java, cryptography

I'd like to generate timestamps in what I thought was a reasonably easy way - but the maths is escaping me!

I'd like to generate 2 timestamps (in millis since epoch) that meet the following criteria:

1. They are equal.
2. They are equal when generated within 10 seconds of each other.
3. They "expire" after a number of minutes - say min 5, max 10?. (i.e. The timestamp future dated)

Use case is like :

- Client A requests the current time from Server A - uses the response to work out it's own clock drift.
- Client A generates an expiry timestamp based on Server A time and sends to Server B (encrypted - so I can't just read it)
- Server B generates an identical timestamp with an identical expiry assuming that Server A is less than 10secs out of sync with Server B.

Example:

```
Time SvrA    Time SvrB    Client A    Server B

11:53.00     11:53.09     12:00.00    12:00.00
11:53.09     11:53.00     12:00.00    12:00.00
11:54.59     11:55.00     12:00.00    12:00.00
11:54.59     11:55.08     12:00.00    12:00.00 - could be 12:05 as long as they match
12:00.00     11:59.59     12:05.00    12:05.00 - could be 12:10 etc...
```

etc....

Ideally I'd like something that just works on Longs - and steers clear of Java Calendars

Comment: Why not just use millisecond timestamps and check if the absolute value of their difference is less than `10 * 1000` (10s) and the oldest is not more than 10mins?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use millisecond timestamps and check if the absolute value of their difference is 10s and the oldest is not more than 10mins?

```
public static final long MAX_SKEW = 10 * 1000; // 10 seconds.
public static final long MAX_AGE = 10 * 60 * 1000; // 10 minutes.
public static boolean timestampsMatch(long t1, long t2) {
  if (Math.abs(t1 - t2) > MAX_SKEW) { return false; }
  final long oldest = Math.min(t1, t2);
  final long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
  if ((now - oldest) > MAX_AGE) { return false; }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned - Server B can't see the timestamp passed in by Client A - so comparing them is impossible :-)
To elaborate - the timestamps are to be used for encrypting & decrypting time-sensitive data - so both need to be able to generate the same key independently